# creating and populating multiple columns with a loop based on the values in another data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    speed <- c(61,24,3,10,18,19,12,12,7,9)
    distance <-c(58,111,92,93,84,103,83,93,88,81)
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(speed, distance))
```

What I would like is to sort my speed variable into different columns based on their distance value. For example, for the example dataframe I would like it to look like this:

```
    under50 <- rep(NA,10)
    under100<- c(61,3,10,18,12,12,7,9,NA,NA)
    under150 <- c(61,24,3,10,18,19,12,12,7,9)
    df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(under50, under100, under150))
```

I would like it to be as automated as possible since I have 23 dataframes each with 100+ rows, but am not sure where to start. Any help would be muchly appreciated!!

Comment: You should tag this question with the language you are talking about if you want people who might be able to answer this question to see it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added additional tags. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have also fixed the `data.frame` tag for you. (Pro tip: hover over a tag to get a description and make sure it's the right one.)

Comment: Aren't values `12,12,7,9` supposed to be under 100 too?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you changes it wrong again, `under150` should be equal to `df$speed`

Comment: I've edited it, otherwise your question doesn't make any sense

Comment: There it is again, `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` Argh.  There's a function for that, it's `data.frame(speed, distance)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is yet another way:

```
breaks=c(50,100,150)
result <- data.frame(sapply(breaks,function(x)with(df,ifelse(distance<x,speed,NA))))
result <- sapply(result,function(x)c(na.omit(x),rep(NA,sum(is.na(x)))))
colnames(result) <- paste0("under",breaks)
result
#       under50 under100 under150
#  [1,]      NA       61       61
#  [2,]      NA        3       24
#  [3,]      NA       10        3
#  [4,]      NA       18       10
#  [5,]      NA       12       18
#  [6,]      NA       12       19
#  [7,]      NA        7       12
#  [8,]      NA        9       12
#  [9,]      NA       NA        7
# [10,]      NA       NA        9
```

The line:

```
result <- data.frame(sapply(breaks,function(x)with(df,ifelse(distance<x,speed,NA))))
```

takes advantage of the `ifelse(...)` function ro return `speed` or `NA` depending on the value of `distance`. The line:

```
result <- sapply(result,function(x)c(na.omit(x),rep(NA,sum(is.na(x)))))
```

moves the NA's to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean vectors to select elements, allowing you to select elements in the speed vector by doing a logical check on all elements in the distance vector.

```
under50 <- speed[distance<50]
```

This could extended to multiple distances;

```
cutoffs <- c(50,100,150)
under <- matrix(nrow=length(distance),ncol=length(cutoffs))
for (cutoff in 1:length(cutoffs)){
  under[,cutoff] <- speed[distance<cutoffs[cutoff]]
}
```

Which you could again extend to multiple data.frames. I haven't actually tested the above loop, and if you have many (large) data.frames loops could get slow.